# wvdial error on ARM

Tags: arm, debian, 3g

I have debian 6.0 on ARM9 board with 3.3.3 kernel witch i've recomplied many times yesterday to see my Huawei E353 3G USB modem.

Now when I run wvdialconf modem is detected on /dev/ttyUSB0

After I configured /etc/wvdial.conf I run wvdial and get such error:

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.60
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
    ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP","internet"
    AT+CGDCONT=1, "IP","internet"
OK
--> Modem initialized.
wvdial: utils/wvtask.cc:202: WvTaskMan::WvTaskMan(): Assertion `getcontext(&get_stack_return) == 0' failed.
Aborted
```

I have no idea what to do next...

Is there any other dialer that will work on command line ARM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `chat`.

In `/etc/ppp/chatscripts`, you find several scripts that handle modem initialization and dialing; you should be fine with a minimal script that just initializes (`ATZ`), sets up the APN information (`AT+CDGCONT=1,"IP","internet"`) and then switches to data mode with PPP emulation (`AT+CGDATA="PPP"`). All commands except the last are expected to return `OK`, the data connection should give `CONNECT`. Wavecom has some [good documentation](http://www.wireless-products.dk/PDF-filer/RF-Solution-PDF/GPRS%20AT%20Command%20List.pdf) online.

The chatscript should be referenced in the PPP configuration you use, this can be found in `/etc/ppp/peers`; once you have a configuration there, you can enable the link with `pon` followed by the configuration name.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Also this might be helpfull: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd)